# Split characters and numbers from a string to array Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a scenario in which i have to separate the numbers and characters in a single line of string
Example

```
const a = "30000kg , 400lbs";
const output_expected = ['30000','kg','400','lbs']; // something similar to this
```

```
const b = "30,000kg , 400lbs";
const output_excepted = ['30,000','kg','400','lbs']
```

```
const c = "30.000kg,400lbs"
const output_excepted = ['30.000','kg','400','lbs'];
```

```
const d = "30.000KG.400LBS";
const output_expected = ['30.000','kg','400','LBS'];
```

Comment: One thing what comes up to my mind is that you can loop through string like it was an array of characters 
for(i=0; i<string.length;i++) {
 // your logic here
 string[0] // is first character and so on
}

Comment: You realise that `30,000,` isn't a valid number.

Comment: @Liam its totally a string, so it would split the string based on the characters and ignore the special characters 

than i have a regex which would remove that `,` and give me it as 30000

Comment: So you want an array of strings? Because that's not what your question says?

Comment: @Liam you can say that

Comment: Ok, well can you please edit your question to say that. I'd also say this question shows a distinct [lack of effort](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: @digitalniweb its not an correct way, i want something in regex and split which would make my task easier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235968/discussion-between-khushal-chheda-and-liam).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
const reg = /([0-9.]+)(?![0-9.])|([a-z]+)(?![a-z])/gi

console.log("30000kg , 400lbs".match(reg)); // --> [ "30000", "kg", "400", "lbs" ]
console.log("30,000kg , 400lbs".match(reg)); // --> [ "30", "000", "kg", "400", "lbs" ]
console.log("30.000kg,400lbs".match(reg)); // --> [ "30.000", "kg", "400", "lbs" ]
console.log("30.000KG.400LBS".match(reg)); // --> [ "30.000", "KG", ".400", "LBS" ]
```

alternatively, if you want to trim the '.' in case 4

```
const reg = /(?:[^.]([0-9.]+)(?![0-9.]))|(?:([a-z]+)(?![a-z]))/gi

console.log("30.000KG.400LBS".match(reg)); // --> [ "30.000", "KG", "400", "LBS" ]
```

Comment: There seems to be 1 more scenario 
const e = " Gross Wt. 30.000KG. 400LBS."

Comment: do you expect "Wt." or "Wt" without period?

Comment: `const reg = /([\d]+(?:\.[\d]+)?(?![\d]))|([a-z.]+)(?![a-z.])/gi` to include period in strings. 
and `const reg = /([\d]+(?:\.[\d]+)?(?![\d]))|([a-z]+)(?![a-z])/gi` to exclude them

Comment: Can you test this 
console.log("4,810LB. 2,180KG.".match(reg)); // ["4", "810", "LB", ".", "2", "180", "KG", "."]

output expected is [4,810,LB,2,180,KG]

Comment: use the 2nd case: `const reg = /([\d]+(?:\.[\d]+)?(?![\d]))|([a-z]+)(?![a-z])/gi`

Comment: could you try that, it does not give me output as `['4,810','LB','2,180','KG']`
where as it returns me as `["4", "810", "LB", ".", "2", "180", "KG", "."] `

Comment: `const reg = /([\d]+(?:\.[\d]+)?(?![\d]))|([a-z]+)(?![a-z])/gi; console.log("4,810LB. 2,180KG.".match(reg));` should be [ "4", "810", "LB", "2", "180", "KG" ]

Answer (score 3):

A good opportunity for you to learn something about formal grammars and parsing. Here's an example to get you started:

```js
GRAMMAR = String.raw`

  String = a:Item b:(_ "," _ Item)*  {
    return [a].concat(b.map(i => i.pop()))
  }

  Item = n:Number _ u:Unit {
    return  {n, u}
  }

  Number = a:Int b:(Separator? Int)* {
    return a + b.map(i => i.pop())
  }

  Int = a:[0-9]+ {
    return a.join('')   
  }

  Separator = "," / "."

  Unit = "kg" / "KG" / "lbs" / "LBS"

  _ = [ \t\n\r]*
`

PARSER = PEG.buildParser(GRAMMAR)

test = [
"30000kg , 400lbs",
"30,000kg , 400lbs",
"30.000kg,400lbs",
"30.000KG.400LBS"
]

for (t of test)
  console.log(PARSER.parse(t))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pegjs/0.9.0/peg.js"></script>
```

See https://pegjs.org/ for more info and docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
splitWeights = (weights) => {
    const weightRegex = new RegExp('(\\d+(?:.|,)?\\d+)(lbs|kg)', 'g');
    const matches = [...weights.matchAll(weightRegex)];

  const result = [];
  matches.forEach(m => {
    result.push(m[1]);
    result.push(m[2]);
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(splitWeights("30000kg , 400lbs"));
```