# Parse expression with JavaScript using PEG

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, pegjs

I have written the code to parse the following expression

```js
!=10 AND <=99
```

To

```
{
    operator: 'AND',
    values: [
        {
            op: '!=',
            value: '10',
        },
        {
            op: '<=',
            value: '99',
        },
    ],
}
```

using [PEG.js](https://pegjs.org/). Please check the code sandbox.

But when I parse the following expression I am not getting the expected output.

```js
=10 AND <=99 OR =1000
```

I want the following output

```
{
    operator: 'or',
    values: [
        {
            operator: 'and',
            values: [
                {
                    op: '=',
                    value: '10',
                },
                {
                    op: '<=',
                    value: '99',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            op: '=',
            value: '1000',
        },
    ],
}
```

code sandbox:https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-testing-sandbox-forked-h5xh5?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use string functions to parse comparison operators, make them a part of your grammar. For chained operations like 'AND' use a rule like this:

```
operation = head:argument tail:(ws AND ws argument)*
```

and handle `head` and `tail` accordingly in the code block.

Complete example:

```
expression = and

and = head:or tail:(ws "OR" ws or)* { 
    return tail.length ? {op: 'or', values: [head].concat(tail.map(r => r.pop()))} : head
} 

or = head:not tail:(ws "AND" ws not)* { 
    return tail.length ? {op: 'and', values: [head].concat(tail.map(r => r.pop()))} : head
}

not 
    = "NOT" ws right:not { return {op: 'not', right} }
    / factor

factor
    = op:operator value:primary { return {op, value} }
    / value:primary { return {value} }

operator = '!=' / '<=' / '>=' / '<' / '>' / '='  

primary = name / number / '(' expression ')'

name = a:[A-Za-z_] b:[0-9a-zA-Z_]* { return a + b.join("") }

number = a:[0-9]+ { return a.join("") }

ws = [ \t]+
```

Comment: I'm not convinced by `factor = operator primary / primary`, unless there is some evidence that the intent is to default to the equality operator. The syntax seems to have an implicit first operand and the factors are operations using that implicit value. `>= 3 OR 4` doesn't make sense unless it's interpreted in COBOL, and the grammar doesn't embody COBOL syntax.

Comment: ... although that would be an interesting challenge :-)

Comment: @georg Thanks for the solution. You save my day... :)